# How to change font of select list items in the drop down

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, fonts

I've got a select menu that has a given font applied to it. In the code its called 'WebSymbolsRegular'. Now I'm looking to have just the first menu item not have this font applied to it. I'm using jquery mobile and I've managed to change the font of the first element when its displayed in the select BUT I am unable to change the font of first element in the drop down, see picture:

[image]

So the 'Please select a condition rating' is perfect but as you can see in the drop down the 'WebSymbolsRegular' takes over and I get gibberish. I would like to change this. Here is the code I have:

CSS:
    .stars .ui-btn-inner
    {
      font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
      color: #eab92d;
    }

```
.stars .ui-btn-inner .firstitem
{
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
  color: white;
}

.firstitem
{
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
}
```

The .ui-btn-inner is needed beacause jquery mobile adds its own mark up to the element.

HTML:

```
<span class="stars">
<select id="AddbookConditionSelect" style="color: #eab92d; font-family: WebSymbolsRegular;">
    <option value="0" class="firstitem">Please select a condition rating</option>
    <option value="1">R</option>
    <option value="2">RR</option>
    <option value="3">RRR</option>
    <option value="4">RRRR</option>
    <option value="5">RRRRR</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

The reason for using R's is because the 'WebSymbolsRegular' font changes this to stars which is the desired effect. Any ideas on how I can change the drop's first time font to read properly?

Comment: Try this............      (.stars select{font-family:Lato})

Comment: use jquery in your selected item

   $('classItem').css('font-style','italic');

Comment: `#AddbookConditionSelect option:first-child {font-family: Lato;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile you have the option to use the non native select menu:

```
<span class="stars">
    <select id="AddbookConditionSelect" data-native-menu="false" >
        <option>Please select a condition rating</option>
        <option value="1" class="staritem">R</option>
        <option value="2" class="staritem">RR</option>
        <option value="3" class="staritem">RRR</option>
        <option value="4" class="staritem">RRRR</option>
        <option value="5" class="staritem">RRRRR</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

The first option with no value is automatically treated as a placeholder and popup title, so you are left with pretty simple CSS to style the star options which can appea in a popup, a dialog and the selected text of the select:

```
#AddbookConditionSelect-listbox li a, #AddbookConditionSelect-menu li a, .staritem{
   font-family: WebSymbols-Regular;
   color: #eab92d;
}
#AddbookConditionSelect-button {
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif ; 
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mzxzn5s8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your inline style that will overrule anything in CSS files including `!important` statements. Now you may want to try the CSS3 pseudo-selector `:first-child` and drop the "firstitem" class. I would do it like that (I kept your HTML although I would rather give a "stars" class to your `select` element than using an extra span):

HTML

```
<span class="stars">
<select id="AddbookConditionSelect">
    <option value="0">Please select a condition rating</option>
    <option value="1">R</option>
    <option value="2">RR</option>
    <option value="3">RRR</option>
    <option value="4">RRRR</option>
    <option value="5">RRRRR</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.stars option { font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular'; color: #eab92d; }
.stars option:first-child {font-family: 'Lato';}
```

Note that if you need to support older browsers, you can just leave your "firstitem" class where it is and replace the second line of CSS by this one :

```
.stars option.firstitem {font-family: 'Lato';}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what you've provided, I noticed that there is an inline styling:

```
<select id="AddbookConditionSelect" style="color: #eab92d; font-family: WebSymbolsRegular;">
```

When there is inline styling, it overrules any other styling.

You can try by removing that, and then place in CSS:

```
#AddbookConditionSelect select {
   font-family: 'Lato';
}

#AddbookConditionSelect select:not(:first-child) {
   font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
}
```